# FATAL: data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata" has invalid permissions Docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I faced with problem when create postgres container in the Docker on Windows 10 (on the MacOS is OK)
I get error: FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata" has invalid permissions

full logs

```
2022-12-27 11:40:08 This user must also own the server process.
2022-12-27 11:40:08 
2022-12-27 11:40:08 The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
2022-12-27 11:40:08 The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
2022-12-27 11:40:08 The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
2022-12-27 11:40:08 
2022-12-27 11:40:08 Data page checksums are disabled.
2022-12-27 11:40:08 
2022-12-27 11:40:08 fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata ... ok
2022-12-27 11:40:08 creating subdirectories ... ok
2022-12-27 11:40:08 selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
2022-12-27 11:40:08 selecting default max_connections ... 20
2022-12-27 11:40:08 selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
2022-12-27 11:40:08 selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
2022-12-27 11:40:08 creating configuration files ... ok
2022-12-27 11:40:08 2022-12-27 08:40:08.524 UTC [69] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata" has invalid permissions
2022-12-27 11:40:08 2022-12-27 08:40:08.524 UTC [69] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).
2022-12-27 11:40:08 child process exited with exit code 1
2022-12-27 11:40:08 initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
```

I use such docker-compose.yml

```
  postgres_container:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres:13.3
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=$POSTGRES_NAME_DB
      - POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRES_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      - PGDATA=$POSTGRES_PGDATA
    ports:
      - $POSTGRES_LOCAL_PORT:$POSTGRES_DOCKER_PORT
    user: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/scripts/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - .:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U admin -d pgdb"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 10s
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 4G
```

Where **$POSTGRES_PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I add pgdata volumes

`- pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data`

and added

```
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

it works for me

Comment: I could understand if you added `- ./volumes/data/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata`, but why are you adding an empty entry `pgdata:` under `volumes:` ?

Comment: Error: Invalid child element in a block sequence `pgdata:` is what I am getting. Something seems to be wrong here.

Comment: worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
container: /var/lib/postgresql/data &&  sudo chmod 0700 /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Adding the above permission command in the dockers yml  file can resolve the issue in windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same problem on Mac. In my case I suppose problem was that I've tried to use GitHub folder (e.g. /Users/my_name/Documents/GitHub/pg_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data) I've created  folder for database files in another location and it helped (-v "/Users/my_name/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data")

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Windows 11 and I had started the Docker container from Windows Powershell on administrator mode, and then the container started succesfully. Then I stopped the container with Powershell and tried to start it again from WSL Terminal and it worked, I spent a lot of hours with the solutions provided in the post, so in case that some one else works this work around serve your self :D

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on Windows 11 and successfully resolved it by starting the Docker container from Windows Powershell in administrator mode. After that, I stopped the container using Powershell and attempted to start it again from the WSL Terminal, which worked. Despite spending hours trying the solutions mentioned in the post, this workaround proved effective.

#### Steps to Resolve:

##### Step 1: Enable Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Run the following command with administrator privileges in cmd or Powershell:

```bash
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
```

- `dism.exe`: Windows Deployment Image Service Management Tool, a tool for managing Windows features.
- `/online`: Performs the operation on the currently running operating system.
- `/enable-feature`: Enables the specified feature, in this case, WSL.
- `/featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux`: Specifies the name of the feature to enable, which is WSL.
- `/all`: Performs the operation on all available features.
- `/norestart`: Prevents the system from restarting after completing the operation.

##### Step 2: Confirm Requirements for WSL 2

Ensure your Windows 10 version and build meet the requirements for updating to WSL 2:

- For x64 systems: Version 1903 or later, build 18362.1049 or later.
- For ARM64 systems: Version 2004 or later, build 19041 or later.

##### Step 3: Enable Virtual Machine Platform

Run the following command with administrator privileges:

```bash
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
```

##### Step 4: Download Linux Kernel Update Package

Run the following commands with administrator privileges:

```bash
wsl.exe --install
wsl.exe --update
```

##### Step 5: Set WSL 2 as Default Version

Run the following command with administrator privileges:

```bash
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

##### Step 6: Configure Docker Desktop

In Docker Desktop, go to Settings > General > Check "Use the WSL 2 based engine."

##### Step 7: Restart Your Computer

##### Step 8: Run Docker Compose Again

After completing all the steps, restart your computer and try running Docker Compose with your volume.

#### Reference:

[Microsoft WSL Installation Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-2---check-requirements-for-running-wsl-2)

#### Additional Information:

For those who prefer not to use the wsl install command and want to manually install WSL on older Windows versions, you can find step-by-step instructions in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/wsl/install-manual).

and please do let me know if anything is needed to be updated or misleading